# Iframe not embedding in a div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am facing a weird issue with jQuery `append()` method. I want to append a container containing `iframe` in a div but somehow its not working, though If instead of appending a div containing `iframe`, if I replace this with any other normal div its working fine.

**Jquery/JavaScript code -**

```
var imageURL = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/zZasH6qkn8M';
var setWidth = '90%';
var setHeight = '211px';
var iframeContainer = '<div id="iframecontainer" style="position: relative;left: 50%;border: 0;top: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%)">'+'<iframe id="ytFrameId" class="ytClassa" width="' + setWidth + '" height="' + setHeight + '" src="' + imageURL +'></iframe>'+'</div>';

//var iframeContainer = '<div id="retro">This is retro</div>';
$('#test').append(iframeContainer);
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong with my approach.

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/vo4cg8o3/

Comment: quotes are wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never close the attribute for the src

```
 ... src="' + imageURL +'></iframe>'+'</div>';
         ^
         open but not closed
```

Answer (score 1):

you're missing a closing quote at the end of the `src` attribute, try:

```
var iframeContainer = '<div id="iframecontainer" style="position: relative;left: 50%;border: 0;top: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%)">'+'<iframe id="ytFrameId" class="ytClassa" width="' + setWidth + '" height="' + setHeight + '" src="' + imageURL +'"></iframe>'+'</div>';
```

[Here it is working](https://jsfiddle.net/Ln4x3tdr/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this simple javascript code. instead of `.append` use `.html`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").html("<iframe src='http://jsfiddle.net'></iframe>");  
});
```